# Is there an analytical solution to this matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, vectors

I'm faced with this squared quadratic form:
$$
f(\mathbf{x}) = (a - \mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{Ax})^{2}
$$
where $a$ is a scalar, $\mathbf{x}$ is a $d$-dimensional vector, and $\mathbf{A}$ is a $d\times d$ symmetric positive definite matrix. The minimization of this function with regard to the vector $\mathbf{x}$ requires solving this unusual matrix-vector equation
$$
\arg\min_{\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^{d}} f(\mathbf{x}) = \left\{\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^{d}:\mathbf{Ax}(a-\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{Ax}) = 0\right\}
$$

Does this minimization problem have an analytical solution? Or should I resort to some kind of numerical optimization algorithm? It would be best to find the closed-form expression, hopefully, if there is one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Spectral Theorem to write $A=PDP^T$ where $D$ is diagonal and $P$ is orthogonal. Notice that $D$ has strictly positive diagonal elements because $A$ is positive definite.

A guaranteed minimum occurs if

$$a=x^TPDP^Tx$$

Write $y=P^Tx$ and this becomes $a=y^TDy$. If the diagonal elements of $D$ are $\lambda_i$ for $i=1,\dots,d$ and $y=(y_1,\dots,y_d)$ then this is equivalent to

$$a=\sum_{i=1}^d\lambda_i y_i^2 \tag{$*$}$$

When $a<0$, we see there can be no solution. When $a=0$, $y=0$ is the only solution. For both these cases, the best we can do is $y=x=0$.
When $a>0$, we see there are plenty of solutions -- an ellipsoid of solutions!

---

In other words, when $a>0$, what you can do is:

$\quad(1)$: Calculate the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $A$.

$\quad(2)$: Calculate an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for A, thus obtaining $P$.

$\quad(3)$: Choose some $y$ that solves $(*)$.

$\quad(4)$: Set $x=Py$ $($ remember that $P$ is orthogonal$)$.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're making this way too difficult. If $a>0$, you choose $\mathbf x$ so that $\mathbf x^\top A\mathbf x = a$ and you make $f(\mathbf x)=0$. If $a\le 0$, you get the minimum when $\mathbf x = \mathbf 0$. Your calculus equation is solved by taking either $a=\mathbf x^\top A\mathbf x$ (my first case) or $\mathbf x=\mathbf 0$ (my second case) since $A$ is nonsingular.